# mysql data to form with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code to connect to mysql and get data from one table :

```
<?php

    //Include database connection details
    require_once('sql/config.php');

    //Connect to mysql server
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if(!$link) {
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select database
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
    if(!$db) {
        die("Unable to select database");
    }

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customers");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row['email'];
        echo "<br />";
    }

    mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Now how can I fill this email data from mysql to the form that was create previously safely?

Comment: I don't understand your question...

Comment: your code seems ok. What do you want to fill exactly? Explain better

Comment: I want to put $row['email'] in a form with the id email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row['email'];
        echo "<br />";
    }
```

to:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $emails_array[] = $row['email'];
    }
```

then use `$emails_array` as:

```
$people_to_email_to = implode(";", $emails_array);
```

then your form:

```
echo "<input id='emails' type='text' value='$people_to_email_to' name='emails' />";
```